# Open mutiple intents separately in android

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications, android-alarms

My application generates multiple separate notifications, for eg, `Notification A, Notification B, Notification C.` etc...

If i tap on `Notification A`, the details of A will be visible, after that if i open `Notification C or B, the activity still shows Notification A contents only`. How to make it to update to show corresponding notification data. I'm assigning unique key for each notification.

Here is my code to generate notification

```
CharSequence title = title1;
    CharSequence description = notes;

    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Google_task_notification_preview.class);
    intent.putExtra("CODE", key);        

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), key, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    try
    {

        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(ic_launcher);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();    

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext()).setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(description)
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
            .setSound(soundUri);

    if(priority == 0)
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_low);
    else
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_high);  

    mBuilder.setWhen(timestamp);


    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // cancel notification after click
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // show scrolling text on status bar when notification arrives
    notification.tickerText = title + "\n" + description;

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(key, notification);

    }
    catch(SecurityException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, in second activity i'm doing like `int defvalue = 0;
       
          mPrimaryKey = getIntent().getIntExtra("CODE", defvalue);
          Log.i("mPrimaryKey", String.valueOf(mPrimaryKey));`, to get the key. but here i'm getting old key always

Comment: Hi, in mine if i keep breakpoint in notification activity, first time only it hits, rest of the time it wont :(.

Comment: Generate 3 to 4 notifications, kill the current running instance & then u try to open one after another, in that case it wont work :(

Comment: launchMode means, i didnt get u... did u kill the running activity by pressing home button, then open notifications individually, you would see the issue

Comment: Nope. I can't get it to not work.

Comment: Launchmode means, can u tell me what needs to be added in manifest, ill try

Comment: If it's not there already, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: i mean, like first open one intent from notification, then dont close, simply go to notification section again & try to open second one on top of that, did u try that senario?. perhaps its failing in that

Comment: Nope. I can't get it to not work. Where's the `getIntent().getExtra()` code? In `onCreate()`?

Comment: Oh, :(, in  `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` function only i have added that code

Comment: Hi Mike, i got the issue, i need to override onNewIntent & handle the code there. Hey But on bringing the background activity to front again oncreate gets called, at this time what intent it will have?

Comment: It will be the original Intent used to start the Activity.

Comment: So, i'm doing like this in oncreate then it should be ok na?, `if(savedInstanceState == null)
{
mPrimaryKey = getIntent().getIntExtra("CODE", defvalue);
}
else
{
mPrimaryKey = savedInstanceState.getInt("ID");
}` i will be saving ID in `onSaveInstanceState` method.

Comment: Thank u Mike for ur support. :), at last i did it

Comment: Oh, good! Sorry, I didn't see your last comment. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

**It Will Sure Works Perferct!**

Manifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.nofiticationexample"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >

            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="16"
                android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name="com.example.nofiticationexample.MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name="com.example.nofiticationexample.NotificationA"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                </activity>
                 <activity
                    android:name="com.example.nofiticationexample.NotificationB"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                </activity>
                 <activity
                    android:name="com.example.nofiticationexample.NotificationC"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                </activity>
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
        package com.example.nofiticationexample;

        import java.util.Calendar;
        import java.util.Date;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                try {
                    /***
                     * generateNotification(Dynamically passing the Class Name)
                     */
                    generateNotification("com.example.nofiticationexample.NotificationB");
                    generateNotification("com.example.nofiticationexample.NotificationC");
                    generateNotification("com.example.nofiticationexample.NotificationA");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            public void generateNotification(String className) {
                try {
                    Log.d("className", className);
                    long notificationID = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                    Class cls = Class.forName(className);
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cls);
                    resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://" + notificationID));
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Your Message");
                    mBuilder.setContentText("You've received new message.");
                    mBuilder.setTicker("Your Title !");
                    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotificationManager.notify((int) notificationID, mBuilder.build());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

NotificationA Class:

```
    package com.example.nofiticationexample;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class NotificationA  extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.notify_1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for your effort in making sample example. thank u for ur answer, i wanted to see multiple notification in a single activity

Answer (score 0):

A special thanks to Mike M, i fixed this issue, by overriding the below function,

```
 @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

         super.onNewIntent(intent);
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         mPrimaryKey = intent.getIntExtra("CODE", defvalue);


     }
```

and added these  `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` flags in my notification intent.

And added only `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag in pending intent